# Need example embedding plot with bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

Could anybody give me a brief example of how to use bokeh's embed tool?  I've had a little bit of luck with the `create_html_snippet()` but I need a method that will support the use of hovertool for a barchart.  I want absolute basics if possible, just any example or anything.

**My situation:**

1. novice at Javascript (do I need to do an import statement in my html?)
2. novice at html (haven't made a site for years)
3. still pretty beginner with bokeh too.
4. not running bokeh server, just want to embed static html like I receive from the `save()` method.

EDIT:  none of the resources I found were super helpful but for others who stumble upon this this might help.

```
bokeh.embed.autoload_static(plot_object=myplot, resources=Resources('cdn'), script_path='embed.js)
```

This returns 2 items the first goes in that `embed.js` file.  The second goes straight onto your html.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is not a code mill. Please show that you put in some effort by giving some code that you have tried and what went wrong with it. We will not write your code for you, but we will help you figure out where you went wrong with your code.

Comment: My apologies.  I'm new around here and couldn't find an example of how to use the embed methods within bokeh's tutorial. All I could figure out was create_html_snippet() which is apparently now deprecated.  Unfortunately I just overwrote my graph create code so I actually don't have code right now, but I'll come back by the end of the day after I reconstruct.

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your comment, we have a new Bokeh embed API since 0.5 release.

You can see some embedding examples here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed

And you have here a little bit of docs about embedding:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html

Let's know if you need additional help to work on this...

Comment: Yeah I poked around a bit more and eventually figured it out.  I might be in the minority but I think it would be really cool if you guys could put an example up that used a non bokeh-server method.  I managed to get it working using autoload-static.

Comment: Yes, we have to add more examples, I agree... it is always in our TODO list. If you want to contribute with some examples, we will be very grateful ;-)

Comment: Hey Damian,All your bokeh webpages seems to be broken. 404 error on all.

Comment: The User guide was rewritten, check: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html

Answer (score 1):

I've just stumbled upon the deprecated create_html_snippet myself, after updating to the new bokeh and breaking my code. After going through the docs about embedding I managed to get it to work again, and [here](https://github.com/tpbaeva/BokehTests/tree/master/0.5.2)'s a simple example code which works for me.

Comment: Please consider pasting a minimal-use case of your code here. Thanks!

Comment: The example code creates a basic flask app which renders an html with an embedded static bokeh plot of time-series of random numbers (once the app is running, the plot can be viewed as usual under localhost:5000). 
@Damian - I manually saved the js for the plot, whereas in 0.4.4 create_html_snippet was doing this. Am I missing something, or is this the way to do it? Cheers!